# N-stage rectifier as AM demodulator?

Tags: rf, diodes, rectifier, demodulation, amplitude-modulation

I want to downconvert a simple 100kbit/s NRZ OOK/ASK signal from 900 MHz. In a previous design I found **two** options:

Option 1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftPOOi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Option 2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feEI4K.png)</sup>

L1 and C1 are an L-match (input is 50 Ohm). The diodes are Schottky diodes (HSMS-285C).
I recognize both options as an instance of an N-stage rectifier (option 1: one stage, option 2: two stages).

I simulate both options in LTspice and the output voltage of option 2 is twice as high as option 1 which sounds definitely better to me. I assume this would not increase the SNR (?) but it would make threshold detection of Vout easier when the voltage is larger.

Questions:

1. Why would I pick option 1 over option 2? Is there any advantage of using option 1?
2. Why stop at 2 stages? Why not multiple stages? (I know that the voltage multiplication will be limited by the parasitics and the diode drops). But could there be a deeper reason why the original author used only one or two stages?

Comment: What's the peak to peak voltage at RFIN?  What's the forward voltage of your diodes at the current you expect to draw from the demodulator?

Comment: And, finally, what will the total impedance of your multiplier be?

Comment: ^ Questions for you to consider in trying to figure out the reasoning behind the circuit.

Comment: I'm just wondering, is there any particular reason you're using Zener diodes rather than regular diodes?

Comment: @Transistor: Sorry that was a mistake. I added the info that it's a **Schottky** diode (HSMS-285C)

Comment: @JRE: My question is more conceptual (at this point) but max input power would be maybe 30dBm at 50Ohm and as low as possible (-30dBm or lower)

Comment: @JRE: According to my spice simulation, each stage halves the input inpedance (e.g. 1 stage 67 - 522j Ohm and 2 stages 33 - 255j Ohm). Is this what you want to get to?

Comment: @divB: The Schottky symbol is hidden down at the bottom of the regular diode properties under "DISP". Just note it in your post rather than edit the schematics.

Comment: @divB:  Yeah, that's part of it.  Each stage increases the load on your antenna.  That's going to mess with your matching circuit.  The other thing is that you have to have enough signal voltage to overcome the diode forward voltage.

Comment: @JRE If this is the answer to the question it would be great if you write an answer for questions 1,2 it and explain the reasoning. So far all I know is each stage loads the antenna more but I can still design the L-match such that the antenna always sees 50 Ohm, no matter the amount of stages.

Comment: stupid question, because it's hard for me to see how one could model the frequency-selective behaviour of this (short of simulation): assuming this is meant for a receiver, how do you make sure your circuit is sensitive at 900 MHz, and not, say, to GSM phones and ISM band emissions elsewhere?

Comment: @MarcusMüller this ia a great question ... this is from a passive RFID tag and I think these tags don't have a high selectivity in general. I assume the reason is that the typical sensitivity of a tag is far higher than everything else (> -20dBm) ...

Comment: @divB ah in that case, the antenna might be fairly selective to begin with (or false alarms just don't matter)

Comment: @MarcusMüller *"(or false alarms just don't matter)"* Wouldn't that just be bit errors? It would be up to the protocol to solve that.

Comment: no, that would mostly be the tag turning on although there's no reader.

Answer (score 1):

You might achieve more sensitivity by operating a diode with 1uA or 10uA of bias current. A 1 MegOhm resistor from +9 volts will do this. For reduced capacity, use a small leaded resistor??

You need a R+C load: 100Kohm and 10pF is 1uS time constant, giving you excellent response to your 10uS bit times.

Your ZERO RF output will be +9v * 100,000/1,000,000 = 0.9 volts.

You can drop the Grounded resister (the 100,000) to 10K if you want.

The primary load on the RF input, given the diode is biased ON, will be the 10pF capacitor.

Given 1pF = -J 159 ohms at 1GHz, the 10pF will be -j 16 ohms, a heavy load on an antenna. You might use just a few picoFarads, then into 10Kohm series into 100pF shunt, into opamp buffer. This light load should give 5X larger rectified voltage.

Given the diode is biased ON, a fast diode should handle the 900MHz.

Given 0dBm across 50 ohms is 0.632 volts PP, and -20 dBm is 0.0632 volts PP, and -40dBm is 0.00632 volt PP (a mere 6 milliVolts), you have interesting possibilities here.

===========================

To recover the OOK/AM modulation, you need to remove the RF (1.1 nanosecond period) yet preserve the 10uS bit times.

A 3_component cascade: 220,000 ohm to +1v, into the diode anode, with the cathode to a 10,000 ohm resistor (in parallel with 100 pFcap to remove the 900MHz), should do this.

GIven 100pF has only 1.6 ohms reactance, compared to the 10,000 ohm resistor, the RF will be well suppressed limited by your Ground Plane and your lead inductance.

Comment: This is nice additional info but unfortunately does not address the actual two questions at all. Apart from this: 1.) There is only 1-3V supply. You would connect the 1MOhm from there to Vout node? 2.) Why do you need explicit R load? The diodes have parasitic resistance

Answer (score 0):

The diode pump will give more DC volts when the RF input is well above the voltage drops of the unbiased diodes.As you add more stages the Diode drops also go up in proportion.This means that weak signal detection will not be improved by using a large number of stages .Capacitive loading will also become a problem at your frequencies.I did consider this for an AM detecter at 455KHz.